# oauth2 where to store client secret on android phone in order to request access token?

Tags: oauth-2.0

I did my own authentication server with oath2 (not using any facebook or google) and I was wondering where to first store the client secret on the mobile. As the shared preferences can be hack on rooted phone AND the acces token request needs the client id I'm facing a problem.

(Please do not mark this question as duplicated as I didn't find the answer on a similar post)

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are facing? And as far as the shared preferences are concerned, the Android device doesn't need to be root. (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Comment: Hi, I m not sayint the device has to be rooted  ! I m sayint that a person that has a rooted phone can acces to the shared pref and then acees to the client secret....

It s not a question about shared pref but a "how to do" in oauth2 mecanism. THe auth2 protocol need the client id to retrieve an acces token with the grant password. And storing the client id on the phone seems to be bad. So how to retrieve an acces token when the user set his password and login. And then does I have to store the acces token in the shared preferences too ? Thanks for help !

Answer (score 4):

You need the client Id and secret when you are using the Authorization Code flow. This flow is normally used in situations where the client is highly trusted, for example an API running form the server. Implicit flow is the better option in cases where you do not want to store the client secret.

Implicit flow differs from Authorization code flow with response returned form the authorization server. Implicit flow returns the access_token directly. To have a valid session for longer periods you can request refresh token along with access tokens. And refresh tokens can be used to obtain a new access token when the current access token becomes invalid or expires.

Please let me know if you have any other questions.

Thank you,
Soma.

Comment: Oh man, really thanks for your response and sorry for my english… It s me to thank you :) !

Let me first explain the situation. It s a basic use case. I did an oauth2 server for my app on mobile device (android and iOS) without website. It NOT planned to be used for other applications (at least for the moment…). As I have understood, it s the goal of the authorization flow with this redirect you have to pass when creating a new client.

Can you explain me please the process step by step ?

Comment: What represents a client ? In my case, do I have only 1 client for all my users as I m the only « actor » of my oath server ? In that case I understand how to do the implicit by passing the client Id when the user log in.

But I still don t understand what is the purpose of the redirect url when requesting an access token in implicit flow and how to deal with on mobile…

Really thanks for help. I think this noob question can help other people.

Comment: Hi, the user is redirected to login page when needs authentication. The redirect uri tells the authentication server where to send the user once authenticated. IOS app could be one client and Android could be another. Clients are pre-registered on the authentication server. Hope this helps. Thank you.

Comment: Hi thanks again for the response, but I don't understand how the implicite flow is what I have to use. 
How can I deal with a redirect url from a mobile ?! I want the user to login and register inside the app it s why I m using the pasword grant flow ! If it make sens to say that I have an unique client for all my usersn so I send to the phone only the clientId and I retriev the secret from the server, but I m not sure that is the right way....